# How to exit all the calling scripts in bash?

Tags: bash, exit

Lets say I have the following scripts

**a.sh**

```
echo in a
if test 1 -ne 2; then
        echo oops
        exit 1
fi
```

**b.sh**

```
echo in b
./a.sh
echo in b 2
```

When running b.sh, I want it to exit if a.sh exited.
How do I do this?

(The current output is

```
in b
in a
oops
in b 2
```

And that's not what I want)

Thanks,
Rivka

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check return status of a command, corresponding variable is `$?`.
alternatively, you can short-circuit using `command || exit`

Answer (score 1):

```
echo in b
./a.sh && echo in b 2
```

This basically checks that the first script does not exit non-zero. If that is true, and only then will it run the second function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way you can do it without explicitly checking the return status of the subshell, e.g.:

```
# This will run b.sh, and if that exits with a non-zero status, we will also
# exit with that same status; otherwise, we continue.
./b.sh || echo $?
```