# How to exit calling script in csh?

Tags: exit, csh

I have a `csh` script (`a.csh`) which calls another (`./b.csh`). How do I exit from `a.csh` if some condition is not satisfied while running `b.csh`?

Here is how I call `b.csh`

```
b.csh >&! b.csh.log
```

There is a related question for `bash` [How to exit all the calling scripts in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216200/how-to-exit-all-the-calling-scripts-in-bash).

Answer (score 0):

Inside `b.csh`, use this to terminate `a.csh` without terminating `b.csh`:

```
set PPID = `ps -ef | awk -v pid="$$" '{if ($2 == pid) {print $3}}'`
kill $PPID
```

In bash-like shells, `$PPID` is defined, but for csh we have to extract it manually.

`$$` returns the current process ID (pid) (that is, the pid of `b.csh`).